# Can the equation $ax^2+by^2=cz^2$ be solved in integers (excluding trivial solutions)?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

Suppose $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$ and are each squarefree. Is there a general solution for this equation?

I found that for this equation to be soluble in integers there are three necessary and sufficient conditions which are $ab,bc$ and $ac$ should be quadratic residues $\bmod c,\bmod a$ and $\bmod b$ respectively. That is, the equations

$$
ab\equiv\alpha^2 \hspace{-0.8em}\pmod{c} \\
bc\equiv\beta^2 \hspace{-0.8em}\pmod{a} \\
ac\equiv\gamma^2 \hspace{-0.8em}\pmod{b}
$$
should be solvable. These conditions can be easily derived from the given equation assuming that $a,b$ and $c$ are relatively prime in pairs, but I cannot understand how these are the only sufficient conditions and how the equation is solvable if these conditions are satisfied.

Comment: The formula in the General form looks like this.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738446/solutions-to-ax2-by2-cz2/738527#738527

Answer (score 3):

This is discussed in great detail [here.](http://www.math.brown.edu/~bviray/teaching/Conics.pdf) See in particular:[this theorem of Legendre](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s24/sh/dbea0adb-086b-4e09-8977-538575657570/8106d1d60888fd047a01975f1445f58f). Those who don't want to read Ireland and Rosen can find a proof [here.](http://public.csusm.edu/aitken_html/notes/legendre.pdf)

Comment: It would be very helpful to point out what the symbol $\Box$ in the referenced theorem of Legendre means. Is it just any constant? Or some kind of determinant, maybe?

Comment: Why is there a minus sign in the last congruence?

Comment: @pyramids the simple means "square" (a quadratic residue).

Comment: Thanks, Igor. I guess that was kind of obvious, but somehow I didn't get it, so thanks for clarifying.