# When $Ax^2+By^2=z^2$ has a solution in integers?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

Consider the Diophantine equation $Ax^2+By^2=z^2$, with positive integer parameters $A$ and $B$ (not necessarily square-free or co-prime). When does this equation have a non-trivial solution? Can one give a comprehensible necessary and sufficient condition that $A$ and $B$ must satisfy?

I am aware of the Legendre theorem, but it assumes that $A$ and $B$ be co-prime and square-free; can one somehow get around this assumption?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why would you want to remove Legendre's hypotheses? If you start with $10 x^2 + 15 y^2 = z^2,$ it just turns into $2 x^2 + 3 y^2 = 5 w^2.$ Furthermore, each such problem has a slightly different reduction to the Legendre theorem.

Comment: square factors do not matter, you can absorb those into the other two variables.

Comment: The formula there.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738446/solutions-to-ax2-by2-cz2/738527#738527  Only we must not forget to consider all equivalent quadratic forms.

Comment: @Will Jagy: your reduction from $10x^2+15y^2=z^2$ to $2x^2+3y^2=5z^2$ is based on the fact that $5$ is a prime. In my case, the coefficients $A$ and $B$ depend on more parameters and I cannot find explicitly their prime factorization.

Comment: If you can't explicitly find the prime factorization, you can't determine whether there's a nontrivial solution.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614005/can-the-equation-ax2by2-cz2-be-solved-in-integers-excluding-trivial-solut

(virtually a duplicate taking into account “absorption” considerations expressed in comments).